# JavaScriptSerializer.Seriarelize() doesn't return json

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem in this code, I expect my code to return a json object but it returns string .

Could anyone helps?

```
public string FunctionName()
{
    // Return JSON data
    Object a = "Mash";
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string retJSON = js.Serialize(a);
    return retJSON;

}
```

Comment: Show what you get in retJSON. And what is wrong with it.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"Mash"</string>

Comment: JSON is of course a string representation of the object in its format. What more you are expecting?

Comment: @JavaFan Why are you posting xml? Are you confusing json with xml or do you not care if you're getting either?

Comment: it is the output as it is

Comment: JSON **is** a string!!!

Answer (score 2):

> ... but it returns string

This is the expected result. JSON is a format which is really a string. You can format the json or even display it in a tree structure, but the return argument is string.

Perhaps i should ask, why is it a problem that you're getting a string? What do you need to do with the json?

Instead of serializing an object that looks like a string, try serializing a real object - an object with multiple properties or fields. That will probably look more real to you? json formatting a single string will produce a very simple string ;)

EDIT (figured i put it here):
A simple example would be

```
dynamic a = new { name = "Mash" };
```

or

```
public class JavaFan
{
    public string name;
}

var a = new JavaFan { name = "Mash" };
```

Comment: that does not look like json at all, perhaps you mean { name: "Mash" } - in that case: dynamic a = new {name= "Mash"};

Comment: I get this error The type or namespace name 'dynamic' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JavaFan What version of .net are you using? If dynamic is not supported, try the other (class) example

Comment: What version of .net are you using? 3.5

Comment: I get this error   System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Web.HttpContext'.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output in your case as per the second comment is XML serialization. This you can achieve with XmlSerializer. You can find the example at [XmlSerializer example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815813)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string FunctionName()
        {
            // Return JSON data
            Object a = new ObjectTest() {TestString = "Mash"};
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string retJSON = js.Serialize(a);
            return retJSON;
        }

        public class ObjectTest
        {
            public string TestString { get; set; }
        }
```

serialization of plain string in json format will be always same. Try something with properties

Comment: I get this error System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Web.HttpContext'.

Comment: Which project type you calling from? web application or windows

Answer (score 0):

```
string value in json format are same , when check your json function convert datetine to json, when it return this format`"\/Date(1454583115774)\/"` this is pure json  

 public string FunctionName()
        {
            Object a = DateTime.Now;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string retJSON = js.Serialize(a);
            return retJSON;
        }
```